# Crooked 2D array when printing it on stdout (populating a blank 2D array)

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, initialization

I'm trying to populate a blank 2d array (matrix) with a character `D` put onto a random position.

This is the code which works properly:

```
#define RIGHE 10
#define COLONNE 10

void drawMap(char[][COLONNE]);

int main()
{
    char mappa[RIGHE][COLONNE] = {" "}; // blank, as an empty chess board

    drawMap(mappa);

    return 0;

}

/* Disegna la mappa da gioco */
void drawMap(char mappa[][COLONNE])
{
    int rigaDestinazione, colonnaDestinazione;

    srand(time(NULL)); // Randomizza numeri

    rigaDestinazione = rand() % RIGHE;
    colonnaDestinazione = rand() % COLONNE;

    mappa[rigaDestinazione][colonnaDestinazione] = 'D';

    for (int i = 0; i < RIGHE; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < RIGHE; j++) {
            printf("[ %c ]", mappa[i][j]);     
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

}
```

Unfortunately when I print it, it seems to be asymmetric as you can see, the output is:

```
[   ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ]
[  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ]
[  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ]
[  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ]
[  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ]
[  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ]
[  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ]
[  ][  ][  ][  ][ D ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ]
[  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ]
[  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ]
```

How can I fix?

Comment: Some quick solution: `if (mappa[i][j] != 0) printf("[ %c ]", mappa[i][j]); else printf("[   ]", mappa[i][j]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
char mappa[RIGHE][COLONNE] = {" "}; // blank, as an empty chess board
```

Is initializing only the first element of the array, you can use memset to initialize them all:

```
memset(mappa, ' ', sizeof(mappa)); //<-- #include <string.h>
```

[Live sample](https://repl.it/@anastaciu/CheapMeanLearning)

You should also note that to initialize a char you use `' '` not `" "`, this is for strings.

Just to be thorough, `srand(time(NULL));` only needs to be executed once, you can place it in `main()` before the call of the function.

Comment: Works. Is there another solution without using string.h?

Comment: @anastaciu `sizeof(char)` is by definition 1, no need in this tautology. And it's better to let the compiler find out the size automatically by using `sizeof mappa` instead of doing the calculation manually.

Comment: @ItsGhost, there is, like Ruslan said, in a loop, you can do it in the loop you already have.

Comment: @Ruslan, yes, sizeof(mappa) is better.

Comment: @ItsGhost, glad to help

Answer (score 2):

This code

```
char mappa[RIGHE][COLONNE] = {" "}; // blank, as an empty chess board
```

initializes the first element of the array, i.e. `mappa[0]`, with the string `" "`. This makes the top-left element contain `' '` (the space char), and the remaining row is filled with NUL chars, `'\0'`. All the other rows are zero-initialized.

Compare with the following example:

```
char mappa[RIGHE][COLONNE] = {"Hello","world!"};
```

In this case your output could be (up to placement of the `D`):

```
[ H ][ e ][ l ][ l ][ o ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ]
[ w ][ o ][ r ][ l ][ d ][ ! ][  ][  ][  ][  ]
[  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ]
[  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][ D ][  ][  ]
[  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ]
[  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ]
[  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ]
[  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ]
[  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ]
[  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ][  ]
```

What you actually want is to fill the whole array with spaces, like this:

```
    char mappa[RIGHE][COLONNE];
    memset(mappa, ' ', sizeof mappa);
```

where `memset` is a function from the `<string.h>` header.